# Posting a question with a Karnaugh Map

Tags: support, feature-request

I would like to post a Karnuagh Map which I drew with LaTex and the package Karnaugh-map. However, MathJax does not support this package. I think it would be nice if it did. Here is the LaTex code:

```
\begin{karnaugh-map}  
\minterms{0,2,4,5,6,10}  
\terms{1,3}{d}  
\maxterms{7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}  
\end{karnaugh-map}
```

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not going to happen any time soon — not enough demand relative to other things. How hard is it to render the map on your own system, and then insert an image of that?

Personally, I think that an embedded version of [graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org) would be more generally useful.

You can render your code using [this website](https://texviewer.herokuapp.com/) if you add a bit of boilerplate around it:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}
\begin{document}
\begin{karnaugh-map}  
\minterms{0,2,4,5,6,10}  
\terms{1,3}{d}  
\maxterms{7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}  
\end{karnaugh-map}
\end{document}
```

However, the only output option seems to be PDF, which still leaves you with the task of converting that to an image that can be embedded. There may be other online renderers.

Comment: It is more work then I think I want to do. Part of the problem is that I am not sure how to do it and figuring out how is going to take time. I also noticed that I cannot include attachments in my post.

Comment: You can embed images by hitting ctrl-G, or clicking on the tool at the top of the edit window that looks like a picture of a mountain range.

Comment: Any screen clipper would do fine